# How can a dll image be over 1000 times larger in virtual memory than hard drive space?

Tags: windows, memory, dll, memory-management

I'm working on a 32-bit windows application that can occasionally run out of memory (the 2GB of virtual address space).  When I look at how the virtual memory is allocated using WinDbg or VMMap, I notice a dll image that is taking 85 MB of vitual memory space.  To be specific, 84 MB of this is in the ".data" section, and has "Copy on write" protection.  When I look on the harddrive, however, the dll is only 81 KB.

How could the dll image be over 1000 times larger in virtual address space than on disk?  Note that I am only asking about the "Image", not the heaps or stacks, or mapped memory, just the image - I realize that of course the heaps, stacks, mapped memory, etc. will be additional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating an empty .dll and add this at file scope:

```
char global_stuff[84*1024*1024];
```

That should declare an entry in the .bss section. That is a section in the image that defines zero initialized data. Since that data is initialized to zero, it is a fairly simple optimization to just declare how big it should be when running instead of storing a bunch of zeros on disk.

Comment: I added global_stuff, exactly as above, but it didn't affect the .data section of the dll.  When I run dumpbin on the dll, I see that the .data is 52DB00 (or 86,880,256 bytes in decimal).  It didn't change when I added global_stuff.

Comment: @Sean, did you run dumpbin on the 84k .dll as well?

Comment: I originally tried on an exisiting dll, and I didn't see a difference. Now that I try on an empty dll, as you suggested, I see what you are saying. I accept your answer.